# How can I configure my Docker Compose so my DB does ship with the tables already created?

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I think I have made it work but

1. I don't understand how it works
2. I'm not sure whether this would work on another environment

This is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3.8"

services:

  app:
    image: pfmc
    command: sh -c "npm install && npm start"
    ports:
      - 4005:4005
    working_dir: /usr/src/app
    volumes: 
      - pfmc-mysql-data:/etc/data
    environment: 
      MYSQL_HOST: mysql
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: pfmc123
      MYSQL_DB: pfmc

  mysql:
    image: mysql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - pfmc-mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment: 
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: pfmc123
      MYSQL_DATABASE: pfmc

volumes:
  pfmc-mysql-data:
```

This is how I created my volume (stolen from a tutorial).

```
docker volume create pfmc-mysql-data
```

And what I did to make things "work" is looking up for my 2 containers (Node and MySQL) once my docker-compose is running, and then get my MySQL container ID in order to run the following command: A

```
docker exec -it <mysql container ID> mysql -p
```

Then, inside this "container", I execute the table creation and config scripts. What I'm not sure if whether I'm modifying the volume or the local instance of the container. And I don't know how to actually modify the volume. I don't even know how the MySQL data is being stored...

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Did you have a deep look at the [official mysql image documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/), more specifically the "Initializing a fresh instance" part? Basically you only need to push/mount some sql files in `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`

Comment: Most of the links in the docs are deprecated so I don't really understand the details of them. I was not able to make that work so far.

Comment: I don't really understand which link you're talking about. The paragraph I pointed out is inside the doc. Just to show you it works as expected (provided of course you are starting mysql with an empty data volume) => https://gist.github.com/zeitounator/f2dc63883ed75d0f288aa980fd22526a

Comment: Oh okay, I made it work, thanks. What I don't understand though is, what is the volume at /var/lib/mysql used for? I only included it because I followed a tutorial but I haven't added anything there. Also if I share my project with someone else that volume will be empty anyways.

Answer (score 0):

The whole setup is working because of the below line

```
    volumes:
      - pfmc-mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
```

Because, whatever changes you will do in MySQL (either through scripts or manual table creations inside the container), it will be persisted in the attached volume(`pfmc-mysql-data`) and any MySQL container which will use this volume will have all the tables which were present in the earlier container.

Comment: How do I "attach" this volume to my Docker-Compose so I can share the project to someone else? I have to send this whole project as a .rar I guess, so it can be tested in another environment.